# How to add perfect horizontal scrolling without disrupting the UI in React with Bootstrap 5 rows and cols?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I want to add horizontal scrolling in dynamically rendered react components. The issue I am facing is that if the number of elements are more (e.g. > 10) it disrupts the UI. My markup is as follows:

```
<div className = "row justify-content-center">
       <div className="col-sm-10">
            <div className="row flex-nowrap flex-container-scroll">
                   //dynamically render
                   <div className="col-sm-6">
                   </div>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Whereas the flex-container-scroll is as follows:

```
 .flex-container-scroll{
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;

}

.flex-container-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}

It disrupts the layout. How to handle that?
```

Comment: can u please create a codesandbox and share the link?

Comment: @ShakyaKarunathilake [link] (https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-yalow-jgizm3?file=/src/App.js)